# Django postgresql foreign key

Tags: python, django, postgresql, foreign-keys

I have this models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Service(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=800, blank=False)
    service = models.CharField(max_length=2000, blank=False)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class ServiceCheck(models.Model):
    service = models.ForeignKey(Service)
    check_status = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    check_time = models.DateTimeField()
```

When i run syncdb against postgresql it ends up with error:

```
~/dev-md> sudo python manage.py syncdb
Creating tables ...
Creating table monitor_service
Creating table monitor_servicecheck

DatabaseError: Hash/Modulo distribution column does not refer to hash/modulo distribution column in referenced table.
```

Comment: Are you sure that Service and ServiceCheck are defined in that order in your models.py file? I ask because your output should show that the monitor_service table was created first.

Comment: yes Talvalin correct order.

Comment: Are there any other apps? This code should work.

Comment: What does the SQL that is being run look like? You can view this by running `python manage.py sqlall monitor`

Comment: BEGIN;
CREATE TABLE "monitor_service" (
    "id" serial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    "user_id" integer NOT NULL REFERENCES "auth_user" ("id") DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED,
    "name" varchar(800) NOT NULL,
    "service" varchar(2000) NOT NULL
)
;
CREATE TABLE "monitor_servicecheck" (
    "id" serial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    "service_id" integer NOT NULL REFERENCES "monitor_service" ("id") DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED,
    "check_status" varchar(80) NOT NULL,
    "check_time" timestamp with time zone NOT NULL
)
;

COMMIT;

Comment: What is the database? I had this problem with StormDB this days, that is based on Postgres-XC, but the same SQL works on my local PostreSQL

Comment: Yes I was using StormDB, my code was okay, but these guys were doing manual db transaction for PostgreSQL. I think you need to change Django DB auto commit setting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code *looks* okay upon first glance. I suspect it's a database related issue.

As the `max_length`s provided are pretty huge, try reducing the `max_length`s to something <= 255 or use a `TextField` instead of a `CharField`.

Failing this, try renaming the field `service` in `Service` and/or `ServiceCheck`.

Answer (score 1):

The issue you're hitting is actually related to how Postgres-XC/StormDB (or now Postgres-XL, where I hit this issue) handle partitioning of tables between different datanodes.

Basically, the issue is that the database engine can't guarantee the constraints on foreign keys or on unique constraints. Per an old [article](http://www.stormdb.com/content/getting-django-work-postgres-xcstormdb) on the StormDB site about a previous version Django and Postgres-XC/StormDB, you can do this by setting `loose_constraints=true` on the database. In a modern version of Django (1.6 or later), the equivalent seems to be setting `db_constraint=False` on a ForeignKey as per Django's model field docs (which I can't link to directly as I don't have enough rep).

Another solution for if you're more concerned about availability and not performance is to replicate the data, which means that you won't have the problem, because all of the datanodes have the same data.
I don't know of any way to do this directly in Django, but you can modify your table creation to use `DISTRIBUTE BY REPLICATION` as detailed in the [CREATE TABLE](http://postgres-xc.sourceforge.net/docs/1_1/sql-createtable.html) docs.